# AngularJS Datetime- Picker only one day selectable

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

is it possible to only e.g. make Mondays enabled - and all other days are displayed.

Thanks a lot.

```
<p class="input-group">
                      <input type="text"
                             class="form-control"
                             name="test"
                             ng-model="vm.test"
                             datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
                             is-open="vm.openedDatePickerFrom"
                             close-text="schlie&szlig;en"
                             current-text="heute"
                             clear-text="l&ouml;schen">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                               ng-click="vm.openDatePickerFrom($event)"><span
                               class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
                  </span>
                  </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `date-disabled` attribute to the input:

```
date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
```

From the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker):

> date-disabled (date, mode) (Default: null) : An optional expression to
>   disable visible options based on passing date and current mode
>   (day|month|year).

To only allow mondays:

```
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {

  return mode === 'day' && date.getDay() !== 1;
};
```